# Elastic search import error using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, import

Here is the json variable

```
jsonout = [{"city": "Springfield", "id": 1, "name": "Moes Tavern"}, {"city": "Springfield", "id": 2, "name": "Springfield Power Plant"}, {"city": "Fountain Lakes", "id": 3, "name": "Kath and Kim Pty Ltd"}]
```

The following command i am using to import json variable

```
es.bulk((es.index_op(doc, id=doc('id')) for doc in jsonout), index='dbmysql', doc_type='person')
```

The following is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-10faf5c5bb89> in <module>()
      1 docs = [{'id': 2, 'name': 'Jessica Coder', 'age': 32, 'title': 'Programmer'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Freddy Tester', 'age': 29, 'title': 'Office Assistant'}]
----> 2 es.bulk((es.index_op(doc, id=doc('id')) for doc in jsonout), index='dbmysql', doc_type='person')

d:\nvk\USER\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyelasticsearch\client.pyc in decorate(*args, **kwargs)
     91                 elif k in convertible_args:
     92                     query_params[k] = kwargs.pop(k)
---> 93             return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
     94         return decorate
     95     return decorator

d:\nvk\USER\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyelasticsearch\client.pyc in bulk(self, actions, index, doc_type, query_params)
    445         response = self.send_request('POST',
    446                                      [index, doc_type, '_bulk'],
--> 447                                      body='\n'.join(actions) + '\n',
    448                                      query_params=query_params)
    449 

<ipython-input-14-10faf5c5bb89> in <genexpr>((doc,))
      1 docs = [{'id': 2, 'name': 'Jessica Coder', 'age': 32, 'title': 'Programmer'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Freddy Tester', 'age': 29, 'title': 'Office Assistant'}]
----> 2 es.bulk((es.index_op(doc, id=doc('id')) for doc in jsonout), index='dbmysql', doc_type='person')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally.

We can use json.loads to convert str object to json object.

json.loads(jsonout)

Answer (score 0):

`doc` is likely the uncallable string.  Usually `jsonout` doesn't sound like it should have functions.

Comment: jsonout has no functions. It just json object.

Comment: Maybe you want `['id']`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something in your question - in the error example you have this code:

```
1 docs = [{'id': 2, 'name': 'Jessica Coder', ...}, {...}]
2 es.bulk((es.index_op(doc, id=doc('id')) for doc in jsonout), index='dbmysql', doc_type='person')
```

You have the `docs` variable in the line 1, but you have `jsonout` in the line 2.
And, if you put the `docs` variable instead of `jsonout` into the second line, you should get an error like `'dict' object is not callable` because you have `doc('id')` (instead of `doc['id']`) and `doc` is a dictionary.

So I suspect that also something is wrong with your actual `jsonout` variable value - it is probably a list of strings instead of list of dictionaries.